# Cannot connect jmx to java app running in docker on remote host

Tags: java, docker, jmx

Assuming I have a server in my local network with ip 192.168.100.10.
There is docker container running in it with java application.
Now i want to connect to this java application with VisualVM from my computer which has ip address 192.168.100.20. I thought I had everything configured properly but it still does not work.

I have passed these JVM options:

```
   -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote"
   -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9010"
   -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false"
   -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false"
   -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false"
   -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=9010"
   -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=192.168.100.10"
```

Then I have exposed port 9010 in Dockerfile:

```
EXPOSE 9010
```

Then added this port to docker-compose:

```
    ports:
      - "9010:9010"
```

I am trying to connect to remote host with JConsole or VisualVM from my local machine. In "Remote Process" input in JConsole I put "192.168.100.10:9010" but connection fails with error:
"The connection to 192.168.100.10:9010 did not succeed. Would you like to try again?"

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: So, how should your physical server know that he has to route everything coming in on port 9010 to the docker container?

Comment: Isn't mapping port 9010 in docker to port 9010 in the machine running docker sufficient?

Comment: No, that just tells you container that the external port (9010) of the container is being understood as the internal port 9010. But your docker container is still a isolated machine on your server.

Comment: So how do i do that? Somehow i can access the spring application running on port 8080...

Comment: Hmm, you're right, that should be sufficient...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution above is sufficient and working. I've been using env variable to set port number which was not working properly.